# How to add a keyboard shortcut for Insert Equation for Word 2016?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

I tried Word >> Tools >> Customize Keyboard >> EquationInsert, but I can't seem to modify the "Press new keyboard shortcut" box.

I also tried System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> App Shortcuts, but adding "EquationInsert" or "Insert an equation" did not produce any responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct procedure but:
Write simply the word "Equation" (thats the word you have to call)

Tip: If you aren't sure what the menu name is for a command, click Help in that app and search for what you want, which will then show you the exact menu name.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a shortcut <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> defined, you can find it in the Insert menu.

PS: The location of <kbd>=</kbd> on the keyboard depends on the keyboard layout, so it may not work with all layouts.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Search under all commands, instead of Insert.

Comment: That's not really helpful. If you know where to look why not be specific?

Answer (score -1):

The shortcut for this is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> on Windows.